# Google playstore permissions error on app release

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console, ionic-native, capacitor

Hi to all hope you doing good.

I am releasing an app and found an error of

```
Your app has an APK with version code 1 that requests the following permissions: android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.
```

but i am not using camera or record audio anywhere it simple an app and i am using ionic with capacitor and on config.xml I didn't provide any permissions like this so what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Check the manifest file to whether there are those 2 permissions, that file is located at:

[image]

If it doesn't include the two permissions, you can manually remove them using:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="your.package.name">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `app` folder you should have a folder called `manifests` which should contain a file named `AndroidManifest.xml` check this file for lines like `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERMISSION-NAME" />` and delete unwanted used permissions.